# VB 2010 Converting ASCII representation of Hex to true hex packet

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert a ASCII string that represents the hex bytes to be transmitted via a spread spectrum modem using API packet protocol. An example would be the control bytes that setup the string by the user entering it in through a text box.

ASCII data entered `"7E 0126 10 00 08 FF DC 08 FFFF 10 00"`

The above data needs to be converted into true HEX  `"7E 0126 10 00 08 FF DC 08 FFFF 10 00"` to be sent to the modem.

Comment: What does "true HEX" mean to you?  hex is just a representation for numbers.  The text is already in hex notation, so I suspect you mean you want bytes or a byte array?

Comment: The moment you use the word "protocol" it implies there is documentation someplace that give very specific instructions on how to transmit data using said protocol.  API is usually associated with a referenced library, in this case one that is available to vb.net, and typically allows you to open/close connection points and read/write over them by simply providing a buffer, be it a string or byte array.  You really need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Yes true Hex. I will be entering the modems address as ascii char which need to be converted to true hex. Example, the text 09 D4 FF C8 would be converted to 0x09 0xD4 0xFF 0xC8